# How to filter observable array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am learning RxJS. I am trying to filter only those `data` array items whose code is "ABC" and "XYZ", but getting a syntax error.

This is what I tried:

```js
    myApi(): void {
        this.myService.dropdownData()
        .pipe(
        map((data) => data.filter((item) => return {
          item.Code ==='ABC' || item.Code === 'XYZ'
        }))
        )
        .subscribe(
          data => {
           
            console.log('222', data);
          },
          error => {
            this.alert.error(error.error.Message);
          }
        );
      }
```

Comment: What do you want to print in the console.log ? What means data for you ?
You have syntax error because the return should be in the bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the `RxJS` operator you're using, but as you said in your question, you have a syntax error, because you're using `return` within the `filter` without brackets `{}`, and using brackets to wrap the wrong statement.

So you just need to remove the `return` and the brackets `{}`, like the following:

```js
myApi(): void {
  this.myService
    .dropdownData()
    .pipe(
      map((data) =>
        data.filter((item) => item.Code === 'ABC' || item.Code === 'XYZ')
      )
    )
    .subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log('222', data);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.alert.error(error.error.Message);
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: This solution will also emit a signal when the data changed, but not the filtered result. Just something to keep in mind. Maybe using the `filter` operator from RxJS is the better way here, depending on OPs needs.

Comment: He just wants to filter the result `array` that comes from the API and exclude some items from it, so no need in this case to use the `filter` operator!

Answer (score 3):

You can use filter operator itself: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter

So you can try it like this:

```
this.myService.dropdownData()
    .pipe(
      filter(item => item.Code === "ABC" || item.Code === "XYZ")
    )
)
```

Also, are you sure that it is `.Code` and not `.code`?

Comment: could you post the structure of your model model (IConditionDropdownData) ?

Comment: This solution won't work, because it handles filtering the emitted values, not the `array` itself.